# Remove $templateCache When $routeProvider's templateUrl contains function

Tags: angularjs

My $routeProvider

```
.when('/student/tn/:Id', {
           controller: 'transactioNoteCtrl',
           templateUrl: function (e) {
               return '/student/TransactionNotes/' + e.Id;
           },
           title: "Student's Transaction and Note"
       })
```

To remove cache I've used,

```
MakeApp.run(['$rootScope', '$templateCache', function ($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        alert(current.templateUrl);
        if (typeof (current) !== 'undefined') {
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });

}]);
```

Problem is, when templateUrl contains function $templateCache.remove() is not working. Also I can't use removeAll() because of UI Bootsrap module.

Comment: What value does 'current.templateUrl' have in your alert?

Comment: function (e) {
               return '/student/TransactionNotes/' + e.Id;
           }

Comment: what is the use case for needing to remove it in the first place? Seems like you are creating dynamic templates at server. Should be no need to send an id along with template request. My guess is you have a design flaw in your app

Comment: When it's time to remove the URL, can you check to see if `templateUrl` is a string or a function? If it's a function, then you execute the function to get the URL to remove from the cache?

Comment: When $routeProvider's templateUrl  contains simple path without function it's working proper but when there is function it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my temporary solution.
I've used global variable

```
var turl = "";
```

and now my $routeProvider is like

```
 .when('/student/tn/:Id', {
               controller: 'transactioNoteCtrl',
               templateUrl: function (e) {
               turl = '/student/TransactionNotes/' + e.Id;
               return turl;
               },
               title: "Student's Transaction and Note"
           })
```

and To remove cache I've used,

```
MakeApp.run(['$rootScope', '$templateCache', function ($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        alert(current.templateUrl);
        if (typeof (current) !== 'undefined') {
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
            $templateCache.remove(turl);
        }
    });

}]);
```

This Solved my Problem. Thanks..